# Data Interoperability Tools appear not to be licensed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arctoolbox, license, data-interoperability

I am having problems with Data Interoperability tools in ArcMap 10.2,When i try to use a quick import or a quick export in Data Interoperability Tools , i can not , i click but i dont have any result.

[image: Data Interoperability tool dont work]

what is exactly the problem , for other arctoolbox work very well.

---

*Solved:* I added it from ArcGIS folder's setup. this extension was not installed.